# Can GPO templates in Server 2012R2 manage Win8.1 Win10 & Server 2012R2?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1

We just upgraded our DC to server 2012 R2 and testing Win8.1 / Win10 / Server 2012R2 with it. Just wondering that if the native admin templates in 2012R2's GPO can manage all win8.1/Win10/2012r2? or we need to install new admin template file for that? I found the link below for installing admin template files, not sure if i need to do it on 2012r2. The requirements for installing this file is upto win server 2012....

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41193

Does anyone can find good source of Win8.1 management through GPO on Win2012r2?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2 .admx files are one and the same, so you should be able to fully manage Windows 8.1 clients from your Server 2012 R2 domain controller's GPO/ADMX store.